# Translation request

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

I would like to translate the term "always loved" - referring to 2 parents.
Would it be acceptable to translate this as semper carissimi rather than semper amati?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=carus&la=la&can=carus0#lexicon) supports this use.

> [most, or very] dear, precious, valued, esteemed, beloved:

(Show lexicon entry in Lewis & Short Elem. Lewis) (search) 
It quotes Vergil, Lucretius and Cicero describing *mater,pater; genitor, genetrix;* and *parentes* as *carissima, carissimus,* and, for both parents together ***carissimi.***